# i am trying to Login to ASP.NET Identity from react js using axios

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, axios

i am trying to Login to ASP.NET Identity from react js using axios but the server give bad request error. The code of client Side is following.

```
var data = this.state;
data = JSON.stringify(data);
const response = axios({
  url: "http://localhost:56885/Token",
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
  },
  data: data
});
```

But the same request is working in Postman:

[image: Postman Request Body]

[image: Postman request Header]

Comment: We can't see what data you are sending via Ajax so it's impossible to verify that the requests are in fact the same. Does the bad request's response body contain any clues e.g. a message about what fields are wrong

Comment: @ADyson here is the data "{"username":"admin","password":"Admin@123","grant_type":"password"}"

Comment: Ok and what about the response from the server? Please check your browser's network tab and inspect the Ajax request to see what comes back in the response body. It might give more clues. You can also check the request body and headers to ensure they look the way you expect, containing the right data etc

Comment: @ADyson it says error: "unsupported_grant_type"

Comment: Strange. Check the request body to ensure it is actually sending the data

Comment: have a look @ADyson    https://imgur.com/a/tO8KmqT

Comment: Oh wait I just noticed... `JSON.stringify(data);` ... you're sending JSON but specified the content type as url-encoded. No wonder the server is confused

Comment: @ADyson so there is no need to convert to json?

Comment: Not unless you deliberately want to send JSON and you set the appropriate content-type header, no. Clearly if you tell the server (via the content type header) that the data is in one format and then provide it in another, the server will try to parse it in the format you mentioned, and then fail to read the data.

Comment: So how can i send url encoded data?

Comment: Just remove that whole line `data = JSON.stringify(data);` and try again. You can pass your JavaScript object in as the data and I believe axios will url-encode it automatically for you. Let me know if it works

Comment: @ADyson  i tried it but the response is same.

Comment: What does the request body look like now?

Comment: have a look   https://imgur.com/a/drWOl8D

Comment: @ADyson open the link again i have also added request body of postman which is working fine

Comment: To me it looks like it still sent JSON. Although there are different views of the request body that you can use - look at the buttons in that area of the screen. Which one are you showing me? Also check if you really did remove the stringify line and reload your script

Comment: When I get to a proper computer I'll try this myself, I'm on mobile right now

Comment: @ADyson i have removed yhe stringify line.

Comment: @ADyson I want my request looks like this. https://imgur.com/a/WAdKvQ4

Comment: ok @ADyson waitning for your reponse. Much Appricated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was making a minor mistake. The content type was url encoded but i was sending json data. Thanks to @ADyson who identified the isue.

Here is the correct Code.

```
var data = this.state;
    var bodyData =
      "username=" +
      data.username +
      "&password=" +
      data.password +
      "&grant_type=password";
    const response = axios({
      url: "http://localhost:56885/Token",
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
      },
      data: bodyData
    });
    console.log(response);
```